# Pandas adding Series to keep a running sum

Tags: python, pandas

I am just getting started in Python and using pandas to write a little stock portfolio app. The problem I am having is in my position class which creates pandas Series to represent the number of shares owned of each stock over time based on the trades. So If I bought 50 shares in IBM on 10/10/2012 and sold 10 shares on 10/14/2012, I want the position.shares series for IBM to be:

- 10/10/2012: 50
- 10/11/2012: 50
- 10/12/2012: 50
- 10/13/2012: 50
- 10/14/2012: 40
- 10/15/2012: 40

I plan on doing this by adding series that go from the trade date through the current date and then summing each of these series into one. I am trying to use the Series.add function since I need a fill value to make sure the new shares series representing a new transaction to not NaN the old positions. The problem is I don't know how to initialize a workable Series that can be added to properly. I am trying Series(0) in the below code by that just returns:

```
Series([], dtype=float64)
```

I also tried initializing it with just some random dates with a 0 value but I just kept getting that series back even after adding different series to it.

Here is my code:

```
class Position: 
    def __init__(self, trades):
        self.ticker = trades[0].ticker #grab the ticker we are dealing with
        self.shares = Series()
        for trade in trades:
            if trade.tranType == 0 or trade.tranType == 2:
                direction = 1 #a buy increases share amount
            else:
                direction = -1 # a sell decreases share amount
            dateRangeInFolio = pd.DateRange(trade.date, datetime.datetime.today())     #from the event date through today
            shareSer = Series(trade.shares * direction, index=dateRangeInFolio)
            self.shares.add(shareSer, fill_value=0)
        print self.shares
```

Thanks for any help. I apologize if I am missing something very basic.

Comment: Do you have a small sample that has this problem and can be copy pasted and tried.

Answer (score 1):

so Series.add *returns* the summed series...I thought it just added it to the already existing Series object. So I did this:

```
self.shares = self.shares.add(shareSer, fill_value=0)
```

instead of

```
self.shares.add(shareSer, fill_value=0)
```

and it works.